# Calling removeOverlay does not remove all route legs

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpolyline

I am drawing a route in MapKit between multiple points.

```
-(void) drawRoute 
{

   // Removing previous lines
   if (routeLine) {
      [self.mapView removeOverlay:routeLine];
   }

   // Count how many points are in the array now
   NSInteger numberOfPoints = [coordinatesArray count];

   if (numberOfPoints > 1) 
   {
      // Draw a line between two coordinates in the main array of coordinates
      for (int i=0;i<([coordinatesArray count]-1);) {

      CLLocationCoordinate2D routeCoordinates[2];

      // Establish first and last point
      NSArray *coordinatePoint1 = [coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:i];
      NSArray *coordinatePoint2 = [coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:i+1];

      // Get latitude and longitude of the first and last points           
      double latitudePoint1 = [[coordinatePoint1 objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
      double longitudePoint1 = [[coordinatePoint1 objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];
      double latitudePoint2 = [[coordinatePoint2 objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue];
      double longitudePoint2 = [[coordinatePoint2 objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue];

      // Put the coordinates on the route array
      routeCoordinates[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudePoint1, longitudePoint1);
      routeCoordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudePoint2, longitudePoint2);

      // Draw the line
      routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:routeCoordinates count:2];

      i++;

      // Show the line on the map           
      [self.mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
      }
    }
 }
```

The array "coordinatesArray" is created using textfields. So, whenever I enter different points in the fields, the new route is drawn as intended and the old route is removed except for one line. One old line never gets removed. Should I not use removeOverlay? Thanks!

Comment: Use `removeOverlays` (plural): `[self.mapView removeOverlays:self.mapView.overlays];`

Comment: Anna. No, it is not working. Now, all lines are not removed, not just one. Thanks, anyways...

Comment: You want to remove all previous lines before drawing a new route, right?  Try using that removeOverlays _without_ the `if (routeLine)` check.  I don't think routeLine needs to be a class variable (especially since you're using it to create multiple overlays).

Comment: The other possibility is that `coordinatesArray` still contains the previous line data.

Comment: Anna. Thanks a lot. I did it and also moved removeOverlays to my viewWillAppear method, and voila! I got another problem with my annotation though, but this will be another topic. This one is solved anyways. Thanks a lot!